# Recent Posts widget has some older posts at the top?

Tags: recent-posts

I have this really weird issue I've never seen before and can't seem to google. I was adding some content to this site and noticed that the recent posts widget had about 8 or nice old posts constantly at the top, with only the real most recent posts appearing below it.

http://grainnemhaols.com/

I can't figure out why, I checked and the don't seem to have been stickies, and they seem to be the first posts ever created for the site.

Anyone have any ideas what could cause this?

First I thought It was just sorting backwards but since the newest posts can be seen at the bottom i'm stumped.

Comment: Even if I change the publish date it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: Add the code you use to achieve your goal and maybe there will come some helpful information. This way now (only some text) leaves only room to  guess for everyone. (*Pointing to a site is not helpful because it shows only output and not how that output is created*)

Comment: Its just the standard Wordpress Code as far as I know nothing has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a look and to me it seems that you are not consequent with dates when it is about publishing. (*yes I understand that this is probably a new site and you have added all postings at one moment, but just 'act' as it was posted on those days/years.*)

Take a look at the publishing dates of the `postings`. I would change ALL those `publishing` dates to the year it was actual.

Meaning by that:

- The posting for 2001 has `Published: February 19, 2001`.
- All others have `Published: December 8, 2015`. (*seems not logical to me*)

A little (*very*)simplified example:
WordPress request data from the database and the database only "knows" in this case 2 things;

1. I have 1 `post` dated with 2001 and 9 dated 2015.
2. WordPress did a request and I deliver (*by Publishing date* in this case): in order of year, is the year equal than I look at the dates, are those equal I look at the
   times(*and they are for 99,99999% never equal*).

By changing those years to the "correct" year (*in your case 2003/2004 and so on*) it will probably solve your problem already.

> Edit each `posting`, in the `Publish` 'section' at the top right (*the `meta box`*) you see `Published on:` select `edit` and change just the year, click okay and click now the `Update` button.

I can be totally wrong, and if so, please let it know and maybe we find another (*correct*) solution.

Comment: the old date, was me seeing if I set the date in the past would it get off the top of the list, it was doing that before I changed it. I will what you said later today and see if that makes a change.